# String Compression (C++)

Tags: c++, string

The problem is counting the number of times a character appears and returning the compressed string. For example, **"aaabbcc"** would return **"a3b2c2".**

I have the code (not mine), and am struggling to understand some of the logic behind it. The full code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char input[] = "aaabbcc";
    char* read = input;
    char* write = input;

    char curr = input[0];
    int count = 0;

    while ( *read != '\0' ) {
        if ( *read == curr ) {
            count++;
        }
        else {
            *write++ = curr;
            *write++ = count + '0';
            count = 1;
        }
        curr = *read;
        read++;
    }

    *write++ = curr;
    *write++ = count + '0';
    *write = '\0';

    cout << input << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My understanding so far is that the read pointer points to **a**, and the write pointer points to **a** as well (first character in the string). The character `curr` is then set to **a** as well. The `while` loops starts, saying that until the end of the string is reached (the null character), set the character of `curr` to `read`.

What I am confused about is starting from this line `*write++ = curr;`. `write` is currently pointing to the first character of the string. Is this saying to dereference, and then increment the position? Given an input of **"aaabbcc"**, this would mean that now `write` is pointing to the second **a**? But then this is assigned the value of `curr`?

I guess my other question is how does it go from **"aaa"** to just **"a3"**?

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Hint: when `count == 3`, `count + '0' == '3'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if statement checks if the next read position is the same as the previous

```
   if ( *read == curr ) {
     count++;
   }
```

And if it not

```
    else {
        *write++ = curr;
        *write++ = count + '0';
        count = 1;
    }
```

write the number of reads that was the same

The person who is asking you this interview question is looking for you to explain what happens when the input string is "abc" instead of "aaabbcc".